# Issue with set focus on conformation box in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On click of button i need to see a custom conformation dialogue box. I am able to see it but once the dialogue box has opened then I don't want to perform any action in HTML page until user select any option in dialogue box. I mean just similar to alert box functionality, until we say "Ok" in alert box the control does not go to HTML page. I need the same , My code is as follows,

Css

```
 <style>

        #confirmBox {
            z-index:9999;
            display: none;
            background-color: #eee;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
            position: relative;
            width: 300px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -150px;
            padding: 6px 8px 8px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #confirmBox .button {
            background-color: #ccc;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
            padding: 2px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 80px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #confirmBox .button:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        #confirmBox .message {
            text-align: left;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
       </style>
```

Script:

```
 $( "#locationList" ).on( "click", "li", function( event ) {
var form = $(this).closest('form');
          doConfirm("The Coordinates for Selected location are "+ coodinatesDetails, function yes() {
                    alert("mail");
          }, function no() {
                    //alert("Ok"); -- Do Nothing
           } , function sms()
            {
                    alert("sms");
            });
     });

function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn, smsFn) {
      var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
      confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
      confirmBox.find(".yes,.no,.sms").unbind().click(function () {
      confirmBox.hide();
       });
      confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
      confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
      confirmBox.find(".sms").click(smsFn);
      confirmBox.show();
     }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="confirmBox">
                  <div class="message"></div>
                  <span class="button yes">Mail</span>
                  <span class="button sms">SMS</span>
                  <span class="button no">Cancle</span>
              </div>
```

Comment: You can do this using plugins such as [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), or making your own type of popup window simulating. The basic idea, is to create a div in the body, that covers all the page and doesn't allow the user to click or do anything else, and inside that div you create your popup. You won't be able to fully emulate the native alert/confirm popup window, it will work for UI prupouses only, someone with some knoledge can still use the page by using stuff like Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

You will only need an overlay to accomplish this. Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7MJBR/1/

Html Changes:

```
<div id="confirmOverlay"></div>
<div id="confirmBox">
     <div class="message"></div> <span class="button yes">Mail</span>
     <span class="button sms">SMS</span>
     <span class="button no">Cancle</span>
</div>
```

CSS Changes:

```
#confirmOverlay {
    position:fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    z-index: 9998;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Javscript Change:

```
function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn, smsFn) {
    var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
    $("#confirmOverlay").height( $(window).height() );
    confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
    confirmBox.find(".yes,.no,.sms").unbind().click(function () {
        confirmBox.hide();
        $("#confirmOverlay").hide();
    });
    confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
    confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
    confirmBox.find(".sms").click(smsFn);
    confirmBox.show();
}
```

The Overlay having a Z-index of 1 below your popup, and the fact that it covers the screen will prevent people from accessing the content below. I provided filler content in my JSFIDDLE to show this.

Once the dialog and overlay are no longer needed; `$('#confirmOverlay').hide()` or `$('#confirmOverlay').fadeOut(200)` will make it go bye bye. :)

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Looks goods, But after say cancel in alert box. the pop up will hide and The events are not happening in HTML

Comment: You must hide the overlay in your cancel function as well. Once the dialog and overlay are no longer needed; $('#confirmOverlay').hide() or $('#confirmOverlay').fadeOut(200) will make it go bye bye. :)

Comment: I added the hide method into the jQ for you.

Comment: I am doing on click event on list view. for First onclcik it is working as i need. But when I say cancel and select another list element it does not working. I think you can understand my situation

Comment: I would need to see an example. By chance can you make the JSFIDDLE setup exactly how you are using it?